# htaccess : rewrite urls

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

please help to rewrite Urls from

`http://www.site.com/index.php?cat=catname`

and

`http://www.site.com/index.php?id=productname`

to be like this

`http://www.site.com/catname`
  and
 `http://www.site.com/productname`

i think it will require php check if the page is cat  work with it as cat
 or its product  work with it as product

Comment: Questions about purely about servers and hosting configuration issues are a better fit to serverfault.com. I've voted to move this question there. You don't need to do anything, but if enough other users agree with my view it will be moved automatically for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

category/product check must be done in index.php...

Or you can add extra slug

```
RewriteRule ^(category)/([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^(product)/([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?product=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

but url will look like http://site.com/category/catname

Comment: thank you for answer smutty,
ok   can i use it in  2 pages 
  `index.php?cat= catname`
   &
   `product.php?name=productname ` 
   
   must use it by htaccess to be like
  ` http://www.site.com/catname `
     and
  ` http://www.site.com/productname`
  can this work 
  ==>
  `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`
 
  `RewriteRule ^([0-9a-z\-\_]+)?$ /product.php?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]`

Answer (score 1):

> http://www.site.com/catname and http://www.site.com/productname

The problem with that scheme is that you can't tell whether it's a catalog name or a product name by the URL. As a result, you'll probably want something like this:

> http://www.site.com/Catalog/catname and http://www.site.com/Product/productname

Which can then be implemented in a .htaccess file with the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^Catalog/(.+)$ /index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^Product/(.+)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```