# have url-liked pages instead of GET requests

Tags: php, url, get, request

i don't know exactly what to search for my problem and maybe it look so stupid...
if u see websites built with for example joomla post can be accessed like:
http://test.com/section/category/postName
and also can access like:
http://test.com/?option=component&...

i programmed a fully PHP-AJAX website from zero point and the way i can access each post directly(without AJAX) is like this:
test.com/post?id=POSTID(or with an alias)
i want to access it something like this:
test.com/post/postname

is there any way to avoid those '?' for get requests or any other way i could customize the url for my pages?

Comment: The normal approach would be to use .htaccess to rewrite your "friendly" URLs to your normal URLs that use GET. For example you could have http://www.example.com/category/post-name rewrite internally to http://www.example.com/category.php?name=post-name

Comment: You are looking for `htaccess` (Url Rewriting)

Comment: I have no idea abt .htacess file and how they work..can u give me a good resource for quick learn what i want?

Comment: You can find many example on the Internet. For instance: [htaccess : rewrite urls](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7063156/3361444)