# Routing to Twig free HTML pages using Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, model-view-controller, twig

I am currently importing a legacy system into Symfony and I have a few pages which have static HTML pages which arent using Twig and I would just like to create routes DIRECT to those pages bypassing any controllers etc.

```
/aboutus maps to /web-directotry/aboutus.html
```

Is this possible just from the Routing section?

Comment: I have not read about this yet, but I don't think this is even possible, because it would break symfony's security concept

Comment: You can use a rule in your `.htaccess` for that with URL rewriting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063156/htaccess-rewrite-urls

Comment: In what this would break the security concept? Rendering a static template is one of the most basic stuffs. Routing is related to security, rendering is not. He can perfectly secure this route with a firewall while rendering a static template located in every place of the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can.

In your `routing.yml`:

```
about_us:
    path: /aboutus
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Template:template
        template: "/absolute/path/to/aboutus.html"
```

The `/absolute/path/to/test.html` could be `/var/www/PROJECT/web/aboutus.html` for instance.

If you can follow the "default" structure for views, out of any bundle, you can add them into the `app/Resources/views/` directory of your project.
Then you can use `template: "aboutus.html"` directly, it will be automatically retrieved at `/PROJECT/app/Resources/views/aboutus.html`.

You can find all about this in [Render without controller](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/render_without_controller.html).
Hope you have a good experience with Symfony.