# How can I replace ?p=page to /page?

Tags: php, get, web

I have tried to find out in other websites whether there is a way on how to I replace `?p=page` to `/page` in my PHP page. I want to change from `http://localhost/tapromtour.com/?p=tour_discovery` to `http://localhost/tapromtour.com/tour_discovery`. My code in my homepage is as below:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["p"])){
        $ext =".php";
        $file_name = $_GET["p"];
        $file = "view/".$file_name.$ext;
        if (file_exists($file)){
        include $file;
        }else{
        echo 'no file found';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?p=home">';
    }
?>
```

I use this code to link from page to page. Is there any ways to change from `"localhost/tapromtour.com/?p=tour_discovery"` to `"localhost/tapromtour.com/tour_discovery"?` if there is please help tell me how to do it. Thanks

`http://localhost/tapromtour.com/?p=tour_discovery`
  `http://localhost/tapromtour.com/tour_discovery`

Comment: use `.htaccess`

Comment: Could you tell me how to use it please?

Comment: google .htaccess -> try -> fail -> ask about failure

Comment: Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7063188/5447994

Comment: I know what you're trying to do and you have the wrong approach.

Comment: Do a get request for the param and then do a simple header redirect with the 'echo 'your URL.com/' . $_GET['p'];'

Answer (score 1):

Now I did it as what Abhishek gurjar answered. This is my code in my index.php now:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["p"])){
        $ext =".php";
        $file_name = $_GET["p"];
        $file = "view/".$file_name.$ext;
        if (file_exists($file)){
        include $file;
        }else{
        echo 'no file found';
        }
    }else{
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home">';
    }
?>
```

I changed from `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=?p=home">';` to `echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=home">';` so that it work very well.

Comment: Exactly. Didn't even realize this was here when I posted under the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `.htaccess` rule inside your root directory or directory where you having your project files i am assuming you are getting the data in `index.php` file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Create a txt file, name it `.htaccess` not `htaccess.txt` put this rule inside it then try your url `http://localhost/tapromtour.com/tour_discovery`.

Comment: Thanks. This is really helpful.

Comment: If deemed helpful you can acknowledge this as an answer by accepting it, so it will be more helpful for future visitor!