# how to rewrite a URL using PHP and .htaccess with multiple values

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
newprojectinfo.com/property-single.php?city=Bangalore&area=Rajaji-Nagar&project_name=Prestige-West-Woods
```

I need to rewrite that URL like:

```
newprojectinfo.com/Bangalore/Rajaji-Nagar/Prestige-West-Woods
```

Please let me know how to write .htaccess for this URL.

```
//-----The below anchor tag is my code--------
<a href="property-single.php?city=<?php echo rtrim(str_replace(' ', '-', $slideProjects['city_name']))?>&area=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $slideProjects['area_name'])?>&project_name=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $slideProjects['project_name'])?>">
```

Comment: <a href="property-single.php?city=<?php echo rtrim(str_replace(' ', '-', $slideProjects['city_name']))?>&area=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $slideProjects['area_name'])?>&project_name=<?php echo str_replace(' ', '-', $slideProjects['project_name'])?>" class="img img-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $banner_Url;?>');"> ------------------this is my code pleas help with this above code and let me know to htaccess for that url

Comment: Please put your code in the question (not comments) and use the appropriate formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063156/htaccess-rewrite-urls and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague about what your actual situation is, but as a direct answer to a question this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /property-single.php?city=$1&area=$2&project_name=$3 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).