# how to properly create url rewrite in php and htaccess

Tags: php

I know this question has been ask often. I leverage the links here but still cannot get it to work

source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7063156/htaccess-rewrite-urls)

**what am trying to achieve:**

I have Original URL:

```
Eg: http://localhost/followersid.php?id=101data
```

which am trying to rewrite as follows

```
Eg: http://localhost/followers
```

**.htaccess Code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/\followers$ followersid.php?id=$1
```

My ISSUE: When I type **http://localhost/followers** in the url, it says The requested URL was not found on this server whereas **followersid.php** is in the same directory with **.htaccess** files

Comment: There is a nifty tool called regex101 https://regex101.com/r/qq5NgL/1  It lets you find problems with and test regexes.  https://regex101.com/r/in7i3T/1

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe well this is just awesome! Helped me to solve a problem of my own.

Comment: So you want to be able to write something like: `http://localhost/followers/101data`, instead of `http://localhost/followersid.php?id=101data` ?

Comment: @compuphys That could be something like https://regex101.com/r/DUIwKk/1

Answer (score 1):

It was a regex issue. this is what solve the problem

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) followersid.php?id=$1
```